# Mover seccion fuera de contenedor de html con JavaScript o jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo una estructura mas o menos asi:

```
<contenedor>
<posts>
<formulario>
</contenedor>
```

Pero cómo puedo sacar el formulario del contenedor usando solo Js o jQuery?
necesito algo asi:

```
<contenedor>
<posts>
</contenedor>
*<formulario>*
```

Lo que pasa es que estoy trabajando con un tema de wordpress, en el cual el formulario se muestra solo en algunas paginas y en un pagina, tengo el problema que cuando se muestra, queda dentro del contenedor  y no lo necesito alli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( () =>  {
  
  $(document).on('click', '.move', function(){
    
    // Creas el selector del formulario
    const form = $('.form');  
    
    // Lo mueves despues del contenedor (El HTML como texto, no el selector)
    $('.container').after( form[0].outerHTML );
    
    // Borras el formulario
    form.remove();
  
  })


})
```

```css
.container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: teal;
 padding: 2rem;
}

.form {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.posts {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.posts li {
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="posts"> 
    <li>Post 1</li>
    <li>Post 2</li>
    <li>Post 3</li>
  </ul>
   <form class="form">
    Formulario
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<button class="move">Mover Formulario</button>
```

Puedes hacer un evento sencillo, yo lo hice con click para que vieras como se mueve el formulario de un lado a otro, pero tu lo puedes hacer en el evento que carga el DOM, o como más te guste. Espero te puedas guiar